# How to call keyless array value from simple API response via PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I found this link [How to have a simple array without key from an array key=>value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382609/how-to-have-a-simple-array-without-key-from-an-array-key-value) and I have a question that is hard to find that pertains to this.

How can I call a value from the output of a keyless array value?

Lets say it's sent from an API to your server and you want to read the response with just an array like so:

> *****server: Apache **{"success":true,"response":[30,"0.00026508",KFL]**

How would I from PHP code call the first value? 30. Or next value?

```
if $response->??? == to what??
```

Without any keys sent with this response its so basic as a keyless array.

Not sure how to proceed. Any insight would be appreciated.

Update for code direction so far not sure if this can work or not:

```
$ar = array($response);

if ($ar[1] == $var->var_value);
```

This so far has not worked, as I get error:

> "Undefined array key 1"

I thought it might make the incoming API array `$response` into an array and assign key values for the keyless array.

No values have been set after code has been run.

Comment: if you are getting json string then use json_decode to convert the json string to array, then you can use $arr['response'][0] to access 30 value. $arr is json decode value.

Comment: Thank you will try to access it this way.

Answer (score 0):

When converting JSON strings to arrays and objects in PHP, arrays using the notation `[]` will be converted to a standard indexed array, with the first key starting at 0.

The example you provided seems to be malformed JSON, and it also appears to contain additional text at the start. You will need to make sure you start with a valid JSON string:

```php
$json = '{"success":true,"response":[30,"0.00026508","KFL"]}';
```

Next, you need to decode it.

```php
// By passing TRUE to `json_decode`, we're just dealing with arrays and associative arrays, instead of a combination of arrays and objects.
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

And finally, you read the information.

```php
// Access the data directly as you demonstrated above.
$val1 = $data['response'][0]; // 30
$val2 = $data['response'][1]; // "0.00026508"
$val3 = $data['response'][2]; // "KFL"

// Convert it into an associative array.
$keys = array('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
$ar = array_combine($keys, $data['response']);
$val1 = $ar['var1']; // 30

// Or separate out the variables. In this example, both `list` and `extract` do a similar thing.
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = $data['response'];
extract($ar);
```

If you don't add `true` to your `json_decode` function call, then you have to use a combination of object and array notation instead.

```php
$data = json_decode($json);
$val1 = $data->response[0]; // 30
$ar = array_combine($keys, $data->response);
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = $data->response;
```

**Edit**

New code examples for the supplied comments:

```php
$json = '[433, "0.00032102", "bc1rj7hascxdxnrt3pzyehmp3z221kdxzuakquunpwc", 3, "hui7jnybr5hj"]';
$data = json_decode($json);
$transaction_id = $data[0];
// or
$keys = array(
    'transaction ID',
    'amount to check',
    'send address',
    'minimum confirmations',
    'encrypted transaction'
);
$response = array_combine($keys, $data);
$transaction_id = $response['transaction ID'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I will try this and report back.

The response is not malformed just basic and keyless:

Response from api:

[433, '0.00032102', 'bc1rj7hascxdxnrt3pzyehmp3z221kdxzuakquunpwc', 3, 'hui7jnybr5hj']

                                 
[transaction ID,  amount to check, send  address, minimum confirmations, encrypted transaction]

Comment: `$ar['var1'] === 30;` is non-sense.  It isn't doing anything with the evaluation.

Comment: I updated the code with the example provided here and replaced the useless comparison with setting a variable instead.

Comment: It actually was malformed a bit and so the correct response from the api was the first one.

I got it using this:


$ar = json_decode($response, true);

  $tx_id = $ar['response'][0];
  $amo = $ar['response'][01];
  $addy = $ar['response'][2];


Thank you again all who participated! :)

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I will as soon as I can get enough rep points to accept it as an answer. Thank you